# Does gdb temporarily give pages write permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, gdb

I was debugging a seg fault in a Linux app that was caused by a program trying to change a static constant array structure (so the data was in the read-only section of the ELF and subsequently loaded in a page that was then given read-only permission).

While in GDB I put a breakpoint on the line of assembler that did the bad store, and when it stopped there I manually performed the equivalent write action using GDB. GDB did this without any complaints, and reading the value back proved it had indeed been written. I looked in /proc/thepid/maps and that particular page was still marked as "not writeable".

So my question is: does GDB temporarily set write permissions on a read-only page, perform the write, then reset the permissions? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> does GDB temporarily set write permissions

No.

On Linux/*86, `ptrace()` (which is what GDB uses to read and write the inferior (being debugged) process memory) allows reads and writes to pages that are not readable/writable by the inferior, leading exactly to the confusion you've described.

This could be considered a bug in the kernel.

It should be noted that the kernel *has* to allow ptrace to write to normally non-writable `.text` section for the debugger to be able to plant breakpoints (which is done by overwriting original instruction with the breakpoint/trap instruction -- `int3` via `PTRACE_POKETEXT` request).

The kernel doesn't have to do the same for `POKE_DATA`, but `man ptrace` says:

```
PTRACE_POKETEXT, PTRACE_POKEDATA
   Copies the word data to location addr in the child's memory.
   As above, the two requests are currently equivalent.
```

I believe it's that equivalentness that causes the current behavior.

Comment: @gimmeamilk: Please "accept" answers that answer your question. You can do this by clicking the check/tick mark to the left of the answer you like the best (the check is on the left, just below the votes).   The answerer will get reputation points for accepted answers.