# segmentation fault when reading a value that is well defined in gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have a big problem at the moment. I get a segmentation fault in my code, and I stepped through it with the debugger. From an object I am reading the member `const char* name`, to print it with `printf`. And here is where my segfault comes. I would guess that the pointer to the object is invalid, but from gdb I can inspect all values of that object, and the content of `name` is exactly what it should be. I have absolutely no idea, why I am getting a segmentation fault.

**So what reasons can there be, that my program isn't allowed to read some data, while gdb is allowed to do so?**

edit: for those people those people who still didn't get it, I am not asking for anyone to fix my problems, I just want to know how and in which scenarios a debugger is allowed to read some data, and my program is not. I added a screenshot as a proof that I am not making things up here, but I don't need you to understand my code.

Just some corner information. My program is a Plugin for a Qt Application. It uses the Qt plugin api to load plugins via `lib<PluginName>.so`.

g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1

edit: I added a screenshot to better see the problem. The initialization is done it the constructor.

[image: proof].

```
class PickingHandler {
public:
    const char* name;
    PickingHandler(const char* name) : name(name) {}
    [...]
    virtual void Drag(PickResult) = 0;
};

class ConnectHandler : public PickingHandler {
public:
    ConnectHandler() : PickingHandler("connect handler") {}
    [...]
    void Drag(PickResult) override;
};
```

Comment: Please show the code which assigns a value to `name` and how it is used.

Comment: pls show the initialisation and usage of the string within printf.

Comment: These screen shots are not useful - just being lazy

Comment: you have name().toUtf, but do printf of plain name. Is name a function or pure data?

Comment: @Arne - Perhaps looking at the web page from my point of view might help. (ps. I am not the only one)

Comment: @pm100 I added code for that, that you can see, it is just a `const char*` on the right you can see the debugger with it's value of `"connect handler"`

Comment: @basav ok, I addad the parts of the code that initialize name. name is set via the constructor. There is no other constructor, that would allow `name` not to be set

Comment: @CoryKramer can you please leave a comment, why you don't like my question, me being on hold doesn't help me or anyone else.

Comment: @EdHeal please I am working on my things to make things a bit more clear. You putting my question on hold is not helping me.

Comment: @Sneftel can you please leave a comment, whay you think that my question should be closed?

Comment: @josilber can you please write what my question needs to be reopened?

Comment: @BoPersson can you please leave a comment what you think it needs to reopen this question?

Comment: the question is - is the value readable from name or is printf dying cos of some other bug (previously corrupted stack,heap..). try strduping name to see if its really readable. Also if this is linux, run it under valgrind

Comment: @pm100 printf worked pretty fine in the line above the crash. strdup on name gives a crash, too. So the value really isn't readable. But the debugger tells met that it has the correct value, as you can see in the screenshot that I made.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason (and the *only* reason I've ever seen this happen) why GDB can read the string, but the program can't, is when the data resides on a page without `PROT_READ`.

It can be considered a bug in the Linux kernel that `ptrace(PEEK_DATA, ...)` (system call which GDB uses to read the inferior (being debugged) program's data) succeeds when the address does not have read permissions and the program itself can't read that address.

You can use `info proc maps` in GDB, find the memory region which corresponds to (covers) `plugin->picking_handler->name` raw address, and see what its permissions are.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584449/50617) answer.