# Is it possible to cause segmentfault even when the accessed address is accessable?

Tags: segmentation-fault

I meet a amazing segmentation fault when I am debugging a crash.
It shows segmentation fault in a line which is dereferenced a char* pointer. But when I use gdb to dereference the pointer, no error is reported from gdb.

My platfrom is linux. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does gdb temporarily give pages write permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582534/does-gdb-temporarily-give-pages-write-permission)

Answer (score 0):

> But when I use gdb to dereference the pointer, no error is reported from gdb.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584449/50617) explains why this happens. There is nothing "amazing" about it.

Comment: I got the root cause finally. But it is not related to your answer. My problem is that I enable addresssaintizer and access the freed memory in a special way that asan just crash without useful log.

Comment: @MrPang Your comment makes not sense to me. Please write an answer (to your own question) with details, so we all learn.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is no, it is not possible.

but to find out why, install valgrind, and run

```
valgrind ./yourexe
```

usually it tells you most of the errors you overlooked. remember to compile your binary using gcc -g without -O options, so you can see the source code line numbers.

Comment: "it is not possible" -- it very possible, and happens quite often.